# Is there a way to send AWS Quicksight reports to Slack Channel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, slack-api, amazon-quicksight

I can send the Quicksight reports to users via an email.

Is it possible to share reports to Slack channel?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You may have already found this out, but with Slack's paid plans you can set up an e-mail address that sends directly into a Slack Channel.

https://slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email

You can then add the e-mail address to the Quicksight reporting, or forward it from one address, and send it to a dedicated channel in Slack.